# Laravel Sync Jobs - How to stop / flush

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

I currently have a system that has a Job in it, on the Laravel Framework. My environment file is set to utilise the sync queue - rather than database, redis, beanstalk etc.

Everything works correctly, but early on in development I ran into a few small bugs and I find myself getting notified of the bug occasionally, the failed job seems to be re-attempting to process, even though it's done synchronously. I know you can flush table data, but is it possible to flush sync data?

Comment: How are you getting notified of the bug?

Comment: I have made the job write to the log, via the Log::info method

Comment: Not intending to be insulting, I ask because I've seen exactly this issue in the past: Are you *certain* you're not looking at an old log? Can you clear your development log entirely and have fresh, new logs show up from this? Are you certain there's no other way this job could be firing - some cron, a debug `dispatch` somewhere, etc.? My understanding of the sync driver is there's no data to flush - it's gone as soon as you refresh stuff.

Comment: No offence taken. I have my logging tied to Slack - so it's posting the bug occasionally to my Slack channel, and it's referencing the an old action, which is why it seemed like a failed job retrying...